# infonot a valid enumeration for type class com.sforce.soap.metadata.deployproblemtype

Tags: deployment, eclipse, force.com-ide

While validating Package.xml from Force.com IDE to Salesforce org, I am getting error:

***infonot a valid enumeration for type class com.sforce.soap.metadata.deployproblemtype***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTestSuite</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AppMenu</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApprovalProcess</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Case.Case Assignment Rules</members>
        <members>Case.Case Closing</members>
        <members>Case.Trading Assignment Rule</members>
        <members>Lead.Providence Lead Assignment</members>
        <name>AssignmentRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuthProvider</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Case.Cases Autoreply</members>
        <name>AutoResponseRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CallCenter</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Community</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ConnectedApp</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomApplication</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomApplicationComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomLabels</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomMetadata</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Account</members>
        <members>AccountBrand</members>
        <members>AccountContactRole</members>
        <members>Action_Item__mdt</members>
        <members>Activity</members>
        <members>Answer__mdt</members>
        <members>Asset</members>
        <members>AssetRelationship</members>
        <members>AssistantProgress</members>
        <members>AuthorizationForm</members>
        <members>AuthorizationFormConsent</members>
        <members>AuthorizationFormDataUse</members>
        <members>AuthorizationFormText</members>
        <members>Campaign</members>
        <members>CampaignMember</members>
        <members>Case</members>
        <members>CaseContactRole</members>
        <members>CaseMilestone</members>
        <members>ChannelProgram</members>
        <members>ChannelProgramLevel</members>
        <members>ChannelProgramMember</members>
        <members>ChatterActivity</members>
        <members>CollaborationGroup</members>
        <members>CollaborationGroupMember</members>
        <members>Contact</members>
        <members>ContactPointTypeConsent</members>
        <members>ContactRequest</members>
        <members>ContentVersion</members>
        <members>Contract</members>
        <members>ContractContactRole</members>
        <members>ContractLineItem</members>
        <members>DataUseLegalBasis</members>
        <members>DataUsePurpose</members>
        <members>Document_Checklist__mdt</members>
        <members>DuplicateRecordItem</members>
        <members>DuplicateRecordSet</members>
        <members>EmailMessage</members>
        <members>Entitlement</members>
        <members>EntitlementContact</members>
        <members>EntityMilestone</members>
        <members>Event</members>
        <members>ExchangeUserMapping</members>
        <members>ExpressionFilter</members>
        <members>ExpressionFilterCriteria</members>
        <members>FeedItem</members>
        <members>ForecastingCategoryMapping</members>
        <members>Idea</members>
        <members>Image</members>
        <members>Individual</members>
        <members>Jurisdiction_Loading__mdt</members>
        <members>Lead</members>
        <members>Macro</members>
        <members>MacroAction</members>
        <members>MacroInstruction</members>
        <members>Nationality_Loading__mdt</members>
        <members>NetworkMember</members>
        <members>Opportunity</members>
        <members>OpportunityCompetitor</members>
        <members>OpportunityContactRole</members>
        <members>OpportunityLineItem</members>
        <members>Order</members>
        <members>OrderItem</members>
        <members>PartnerFundAllocation</members>
        <members>PartnerFundClaim</members>
        <members>PartnerFundRequest</members>
        <members>PartnerMarketingBudget</members>
        <members>PartnerRole</members>
        <members>PersonAccount</members>
        <members>PortalPages__mdt</members>
        <members>Pricebook2</members>
        <members>PricebookEntry</members>
        <members>Product2</members>
        <members>Product_Form__mdt</members>
        <members>PromptAction</members>
        <members>Question__mdt</members>
        <members>QuickText</members>
        <members>Rate__mdt</members>
        <members>Recommendation</members>
        <members>RecordAction</members>
        <members>Scorecard</members>
        <members>ScorecardAssociation</members>
        <members>ScorecardMetric</members>
        <members>ServiceContract</members>
        <members>Site</members>
        <members>SocialPersona</members>
        <members>SocialPost</members>
        <members>Solution</members>
        <members>StreamingChannel</members>
        <members>Task</members>
        <members>Topic</members>
        <members>TopicAssignment</members>
        <members>User</members>
        <members>Work_Order_Line_Item_Template__mdt</members>
        <members>Work_Order_Template__mdt</members>
        <members>WorkOrder</members>
        <members>WorkOrderLineItem</members>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomPageWebLink</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomPermission</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomSite</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomTab</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>EntitlementProcess</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>EntitlementTemplate</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Case.Test</members>
        <name>EscalationRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>FlexiPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Flow</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Group</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>HomePageComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>HomePageLayout</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Layout</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Letterhead</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>MilestoneType</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Network</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>PermissionSet</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>PostTemplate</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Queue</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>QuickAction</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ReportType</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Role</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>SamlSsoConfig</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Scontrol</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Settings</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>SharingSet</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>SiteDotCom</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StaticResource</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Workflow</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ActionLinkGroupTemplate</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AnalyticSnapshot</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Audience</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>BrandingSet</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>BusinessProcess</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CaseSubjectParticle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Certificate</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ChannelLayout</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ChatterExtension</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CleanDataService</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CMSConnectSource</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CommunityTemplateDefinition</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CommunityThemeDefinition</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CompactLayout</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ContentAsset</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CorsWhitelistOrigin</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CspTrustedSite</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomFeedFilter</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomHelpMenuSection</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomLabel</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomNotificationType</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>DelegateGroup</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>DuplicateRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>EclairGeoData</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>EmailServicesFunction</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>EmbeddedServiceConfig</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>EmbeddedServiceFlowConfig</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>EmbeddedServiceBranding</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>EscalationRules</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>EventDelivery</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>EventSubscription</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ExternalDataSource</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ExternalServiceRegistration</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>FieldSet</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>FlowCategory</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>FlowDefinition</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>GlobalValueSet</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>GlobalValueSetTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Index</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>InstalledPackage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>KeywordList</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LeadConvertSettings</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LightningBolt</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LightningExperienceTheme</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ListView</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ManagedTopic</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ManagedTopics</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>MatchingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>MatchingRules</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ModerationRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>NamedCredential</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>NetworkBranding</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>OrchestrationContext</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>PathAssistant</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>PlatformCachePartition</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>PlatformEventChannel</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ProfilePasswordPolicy</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ProfileSessionSetting</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>RecommendationStrategy</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>RecordActionDeployment</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>RecordType</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>SharingCriteriaRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>SharingOwnerRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>SharingReason</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>SharingRules</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StandardValueSet</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StandardValueSetTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>SynonymDictionary</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>TopicsForObjects</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>UserCriteria</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ValidationRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>WebLink</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>WorkflowAlert</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>WorkflowFieldUpdate</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>WorkflowOutboundMessage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>WorkflowRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>WorkflowSend</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>WorkflowTask</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>DashboardFolder</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>WorkOrderTemplate</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>WorkOrderLineItemTemplate</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomReportType</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomMetadataType</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ClassicLetterhead</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LightningPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Auto-ResponseRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ProductForm</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuraComponentBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ClassicLetterhead</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>JurisdictionLoading</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>NationalityLoading</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Rate</name>
    </types>
    <version>44.0</version>
</Package>
```

Is there anything I am missing in package.xml ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] to show your `package.xml`, and identify the location of the error if it is given.

Comment: Added package.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can try below options

1. Member's name should be API name and not a label. It is not valid member `<members>Case.Case Assignment Rules</members>`. Please correct this.
2. You can install latest [ANT migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_install.htm) and try deploying it.
3. try with `<version>46.0</version>` instead of 44.0

Comment: Thank you for Reply, I have tried all 3 options but facing same issue.